# Spring Boot Kafka application not receiving messages

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

We're using Spring boot 1.5.4.RELEASE and i can see the following jars in our gradle project: spring-kafka-1.1.6, kafka-clients-0.10.1.1

We have a simple receiver class like below:

`

```
   @KafkaListener(topics = "${mytopic.consume}")
    public void receive(byte[] event) {
        <our code here>...
    }

//$mytopic.consume is being picked up from properties file
```

`

The code works fine on most days and i am able to receive events correctly and process them, then suddenly it stops to receive messages. No error, no warnings. I can see the messages are there on the topic but our listener just doesn't seem to consume them.
I tried restarting application, restarting eclipse, change between run and debug mode, change the name of group in kafka properties - but nothing works. We look at the application after few hours, and there you go - it starts to work again and we receive all the messages which were stuck. Sometimes the problem can last more than a day also. My suspicion is its NOT an eclipse issue, but probably the way enterprise Kafka is setup or some bug in Kafka(lesser possibility since i couldn't find such an issue on google). I did notice this issue even when microservice was deployed on IBM bluemix.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Here are some of our properties(which might be of interest) that we have configured in our application:
    `

```
acks=all
     retries=0
     batch.size=<a number greater than 10k>
     linger.ms=1
     buffer.memory=<a number in 10s of MBs - our incoming message is just few KBs>
     ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG=true
     AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG=1ms
     SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG=30ms
     zookeeper.sync.time=200ms
     zookeeper.session.timeout=400ms
```

`

Comment: Is mytopic.consume the real name of the topic? because i have this on my consumer: @KafkaListener(topics = "${message.topic.name}", containerFactory = "bitCoinKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void bitCoinListener(BitcoinEuroKafkaEntity bitcoinEuroKafkaEntity) {... where message.topic.name is within application.properties...

Comment: @aironman - NO mytopic.consume is not real name and we're also picking it up from yml file just the way you have mentioned. Let me edit the question to avoid any confusion

Comment: Can u post ur project on github? A minimal, verifiabl sample.

Comment: I suspect issue is with the installation itself.

Comment: @IndraneelBende - unfortunately its client proprietary, so i cannot post the code, but the above method and configuration is all that is Kafka related, once a message is received its just normal enterprise processing. However, i can build a new Kafka project with above attributes and upload on github - but i am not sure if that will help to narrow down to the issue, since it will be just like any other sample kafka project. That being said, i was hoping someone could point out a known issue or a property we have missed while configuration which can cause such a hung state

Comment: There doesn’t seem to be anything blatantly wrong with ur configs, for it to behave like this.

Comment: How many partitions do u have on d topic? How many consumers in a consumer group? And have u got a key present when writing a record to Kafka.

Comment: @IndraneelBende We have 5 partitions on the the topic, 1 consumer in the consumer group for this specific issue, but sometimes there can be more consumers. Still at no point our number of consumers exceed number of partitions(if that is you were looking for) and No key.

Comment: We found a probable cause: Our SpringBoot application was NOT annotated with @EnableKafka. As soon as we annotated, it started to work. That being said the required jars were always there in the classpath, but this annotation was missing. Somehow it was working like this (intermittently) for a while. My hope is that this should solve the problem. If we don't see this issue again, i'll post here after a month, to confirm this solved our issue.

Comment: @IndraneelBende - The approach you had suggested 'to post the project on github' would most probably have solved this (i din't post, but keeping your suggestion in mind, we decided to start over and started the anatomy of our project, which led us to this point). So i would request you to post your summarized comments as answer, so i can accept.

Comment: I am surprised it was detecting KafkaListener annotated methods without the annotation EnableKafka. Anyways, glad its working now.

Comment: Yeah, it is surprising and retrospectively we found out that it was doing so for a whole bunch of applications, not just this specific service. I am keeping a close eye if the issue ever happens again once @EnableKafka is in place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing blatantly wrong with the configurations. I would advise you to step back and start over again. Create a new Consumer group. Potentially, also write the code from scratch.

Do tests having different number of consumers in a consumer group, note consumers should be equal to or less than number of partitions. Do tests, with different amount of load of messages and see how it works out. In the mean while, keep an eye on the Kafka Cluster also, do any brokers leave the cluster, which would change the leaders for the partitions. Eventually, you can stop some consumers, and see how rebalance affects your consumers .

Hope this helps.

Comment: And just in case someone facing the same issue did not go through all the comments under question, i would like to add here that its helpful to have `@EnableKafka` annotation in your SpringBoot project, even if you see Kafka libraries on your classpath and Kafka is working without `@EnableKafka`